# Is there a way to find out connectivity possibilities?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, connectivity

I have an app that is meant to check connectivity prior to running the main screen. I am being informed by only user who is trying to run it on a wifi only Xoom, that the app causes a force close issue always and he has sent me a report via the market.

Apparently, the app keeps crash, giving a Null exception error, during the if-then-else statements on the line where it is checking whether the device is connected via phone or wifi.

```
ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED &&  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED  ) ...
```

Being that the Xoom in question is ONLY wifi capable would the check of connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() be causing the crash since it does not have the capability or components? And if it is, How do I work around this so it won't crash but still work for all devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check network state by below code

```
   boolean isInternetAvailable = false;
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(networkInfo != null && (networkInfo.isConnected()))
    {
        isInternetAvailable  = true;
    }
```

in your code, you are using **connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState()** without checking **connec.getNetworkInfo(0)** is null or not

Comment: And also relying on the same thing for connec.getNetworkInfo(1) - ie, the code assumes the device has two non-null interfaces

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

            boolean value = false;

            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                             .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null && info.isAvailable()) {
                           value = true;
            }

            return value;
 }
```